# "Joined the meeting" or "Joint the meeting"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, grammaticality, verbs, idioms

At my new workplace i have noticed people saying:

- joint the meeting
- Already joint

At my previous workplace we always used:

- joined the meeting
- Already joined

Which is the correct usage?

Comment: Are all your coworkers who reply in this way native speakers? This is an important piece of information.

Comment: It could be an autocorrect or typo thing, someone writes "joind" and the mobile/smart phone corrects it as "joint". You should know which form is "correct", did you look up the word *joint* (which has several different meanings).

Comment: Few are native(including myself) and the rest non-native. But at times this is also said verbally. When i had a discussion on this they give a reference of "Joint Meeting" , like for example "In addition, the teams held a joint meeting on xyz to share information."

Comment: In questions please  do not leave out the *research* i.e. "When I had a discussion about this…" or the context "…the teams held a joint meeting". Could you also check that you copied out word for word the replies/confirmations, it sounds like some words are missing.

Comment: There are native English speakers who routinely end a past-tense verb with the "-t" sound rather than "-ed".  If you pronounce "joined" and "joint" you will observe that they use identical mouth positions and sounds, it's just that the "-ed" sound is prolonged slightly.

Comment: A  _joint meeting_ between two teams means that the meeting included members of both teams working together. This is _not_ the same as saying 'Mr. X _joined_ the meeting'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/joint and its Oxford equivalent define the verb *joint* with examples such as "to joint something - to cut meat into large pieces". In a related construction, *jointed* also occurs in phrases such as "double jointed", to describe some unusual flexibility of  anatomy. Otherwise, *joint* is given by the dictionaries as a noun of various meanings.

The use of *joint* as the past participle of *join* is not justified by any reference I can find. The past participle of *join* is *joined*. The written form of what you hear your colleagues saying is therefore incorrect.

It may be that, in speech, the "d" at the end of *joined* is coming out unvoiced as in *joint* rather than voiced as in *joined*.